# java.io.EOFException when read/decrypt from a socket

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, client-server

I have a big client-server program.

But if I send a crypted package, when trying to receive and decrypt it, causes an `java.io.EOFException`.

If I use the non encrypted way (for instance for pings) it works perfectly.

**Client code** (receive):

```
InputStream is = subChannel.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream pre = new ObjectInputStream(is);
ObjectInputStream ois;
boolean crypt = (boolean) pre.readObject();

if (crypt) {
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(SimpleAES.decryptInputStream(c.getAesKey(), is));
} else {
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
}

Response<? extends Serializable> res = (Response<? extends Serializable>) ois.readObject();
req.onResponse(res);
is.close();
```

`subChannel` is a Socket which connects seperated.

I know that I get a response this can't be the error.

**SimpleAES**

```
private final static byte[] iv = new byte[16];
private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";

public static CipherOutputStream cryptOutputStream(SecretKey key,OutputStream os) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec);
        CipherOutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
        return out;
}

public static CipherInputStream decryptInputStream(SecretKey key,InputStream os) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec);
        CipherInputStream out = new CipherInputStream(os, cipher);
        return out;
}
```

**Server code** (sending):

```
OutputStream base;
base = sock.getOutputStream();

ObjectOutputStream infoStream = new ObjectOutputStream(base);

infoStream.writeObject(pack.isEncrypted());
ObjectOutputStream packageStream;

if (pack.isEncrypted()) {
    String tolken = pack.getClientTolken();
    Session s = getSession(tolken);
    packageStream = new ObjectOutputStream(SimpleAES.cryptOutputStream(s.getAesKey(), base));
}
else
    packageStream = new ObjectOutputStream(base);

packageStream.writeObject(pack);
packageStream.flush();

if (pack instanceof Request) {
    InputStream baseIn = sock.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream res;

    if (pack.isEncrypted()) {
        res = new ObjectInputStream(SimpleAES.decryptInputStream(getSession(pack.getClientTolken()).getAesKey(), baseIn));
    } else {
        res = new ObjectInputStream(baseIn);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Response<? extends Serializable> response = (Response<? extends Serializable>) res.readObject();
    ((Request) pack).onResponse(response);
    res.close();
}

base.close();
```

I don't think the stack trace will give you big information but here it is:

```
Ping Response : 8ms
[Client] Added TolkenRequest to Query
[Client] Added RSARequest to Query
[Client] Added AESKeyPack to Query
[Client] Added ValidIdRequest to Query
java.io.EOFException
Fatal Error Exit
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.niton.tele.core.network.client.ClientListenerThread.run(ClientListenerThread.java:104)
```

> ClientListenerThread.java:104 is this line Response res = (Response) ois.readObject();

Comment: This is not related to your problem, but you should use the IV correctly: when encrypting set it to an unpredictable (random) value, transmit it in the clear (it does not need to be encrypted itself), and use it when decrypting. Using the IV as you are is not considered secure.

Comment: I know.This was only for testing . Because if its allways 0000000 i do not need Tod send it

Comment: I'd try to separate the two different kinds of streams: write a simple method to decrypt an encrypted stream and process a few bytes first to make sure that works, before trying to send serialised objects through. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix different buffered streams on the same socket. They will steal data from each other. You need to redesign and rewrite this using a single `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` for the life of the socket.

Possibly you are looking for `SealedObject`?

Comment: Sealed object - `sealed` the deal, very usefull. I am curios if this is 1. intended and how this could be bypassed. How would i do it assuming I want to use a GZip (decompression/compression) -> cypher/decypher -> object in/out stream. All of them are buffering but it makes sense in the terms of functionality. Can you maybe give a reference to a post/blog whatever explaining this further